# How to Resolve CSS/Bootstrap Not Compiling on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node-sass

Help, I was running server when suddenly bootstrap on css was not compiling.
I'm running Node 12.22.9 on Linux WSL on Windows 10 , npm 6.14.15,

Error message is shown in figure on the link below, thanks!

[Error message on Browser Console specifying Node Sass does not support Linux 64-bit with unsupported runtime (93)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42iRi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read "[ask]", [mcve] and their linked pages, along with "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)"
and "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)". As written your question is off-topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.